# nginx rewrite rules: Rewrite /test/ and /test to /test.php

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How do I do this? This seems to work by default in apache, but not on nginx it appears?

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is probably the [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) directive (although this won't handle the `/test/` case):

```
try_files $uri $uri.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this in your site config:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /$1.php last;
```

This would rewrite anything after the / to a php filename, though there are some cases I would think you'd not want that.

Answer (score -3):

```
rewrite "^/test/?$" /test.php;
```